# Hyper-V Shutdown fails - error 32768

Tags: hyper-v

I'm in the process of attempting to automate Hyper-V for our dev\test lab.  I downloaded the PSHyperV pack, most of the scripts work however when I attempt to shutdown the machine it fails with the error code 32768.

I also tried the script off Ben's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/01/30/shutting-down-a-hyper-v-virtual-machine.aspx%29).

However this also failed.

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ReturnValue      : 32768
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/ddcf44cb-7cf2-413d-abe4-b0ed33f5d3fa